# django-haystack elasticsearch as backend and searchengine

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Is it possible without defining another DB as backend use elasticsearch as DB and searchengine In most tutorials another DB backend is indexed by elasticsearch. But I want to use elasticsearch as main database and search engine. Do you have any configuration examples or ideas?

Comment: See [Elasticsearch as a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636508/elasticsearch-as-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using https://github.com/aparo/pyes libary.

Example input:

```
>>> conn.index({"name":"Joe Tester", "parsedtext":"Joe Testere nice guy", "uuid":"11111", "position":1}, "test-index", "test-type", 1)
```

As shown in http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/queries.html